# CSS Submenu lists not displaying correctly, overriding styles issue?

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu, nav

I am having some trouble with my dropdown mega menu, i have two sets of list items that need to be placed vertically side by side with bullet points in the dropdown however i can only see one list appear despite having coded two?

Also the list elements are displaying as black and white on hover when i want them to do the opposite, white normally and black on hover. Also the bullet points for each list element will not display? I know this is because of overriding/conflicting styles i'm just not sure which exactly.

Any help wit any of this would really be great thanks.

**Example fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/DannyW86/8krqjjj7/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="hdr-box">
            <a href="#"><div id="logo"></div></a>

            <nav class="mainnav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">New Cars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Used Cars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Servicing</a>
                        <div class="mega-menu">
                            <img src="img/servicing.png" />
                            <h3>Servicing</h3>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Ut ul tempus tellus.</p>
                            <div id="sub-nav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Book a sevice Online</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Express Service</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Dacia</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Hyundai</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lexus</</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="sub-nav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">MINI</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Motorrad</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Renault</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End of mega menu  -->

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav><!-- End of mainnav -->
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#hdr-box {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}

#logo {
width: 361px;
height: 90px;
background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
float: left;
}

.mainnav {
/*font-family: "Myriad Pro", 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;*/
font-size: 20px;
}

#hdr-box nav {
line-height: 30px;
margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 563px;
float: right;
margin-right: 50px;
}

#hdr-box nav ul {list-style: none; margin: 0 auto; width: 800px;}
#hdr-box nav li {float: left; display: inline; margin-right: 40px;}

#hdr-box nav a,  #topbar nav a:visited{
color: #000;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}

#hdr-box nav a:hover {
color: #02a2e0;
}

nav li > .mega-menu {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
width: 770px;
height: 204px;
padding: 40px;
background: #02a2e0;
visibility: hidden;
/*display: none;*/
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
right: 200px;
z-index: 99999;
text-align: left;
list-style: disc;
}

nav li:hover > .mega-menu {
visibility: visible;
display: block;
}

.mega-menu img {
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
width: 272px;
height: 207px;
}

.mega-menu h3 {
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
}

#mainnav ul.mega-menu ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}

#mainav ul.mega-menu li { display: block!important;}


.mega-menu p {line-height: 23px;}

.nav-column {width: 135px}

#sub-nav ul li {
float: none ;
display: block ; 
}
```

Comment: I guess you're not assigning the right classes in your CSS file..

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with this.

1) Correct this line:

```
<li><a href="#">Lexus</</li> <!-- you didn't close the a tag properly -->
```

2) Your mega menu has a fixed height, remove that.

3) Make the jsFiddle window wider after you corrected those 2 thing and you'll see the menu appear.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/8krqjjj7/8/
```

Answer (score 0):

The second #sub-nav is pushed under the first one because:

```
#hdr-box nav ul {list-style: none; margin: 0 auto; width: 800px;}
```

You're telling ALL your ul to be 800px.

And you should use class for your sub-nav instead of id, id's are unique.